# What is the purpose of these films on CPU/GPU chips?

Tags: cpu, gpu, cpu-cooler, safely-remove-hardware

For quite a while I was wondering what is the purpose of a couple of solid films partially covering chips on my CPU/GPU (they are attached so they are between the cooler and the chips). For better understanding, please see the following picture:

[image]

Recently one of the films was detached. I'm a little bit concerned if it may be kind of dielectric stuff, but couldn't find the answer so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They could be to provide some mechanical strength or insulation between the heatsink and  chips.

As your chips lack an inbuilt heatspreader you are effectively putting all the force of the heatsink fitting on the chip die. A little plastic shim around the die might help to spread the force a little and will also insulate the exposed metal contacts on the chips from accidental contact, either from your fingers or from the heatsink itself.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is its to protect the chips from the thermal compound. Many cheap thermal paste is mildly corrosive and conductive and experience shows that many put to much paste on the chips. If you look closely, the bits where you should put the thermal compound are **not** covered.

Comment: Makes sense, but on the GPU chip there is a lot of thermal compound under the film (and was there from very beginning, when I first time opened the laptop)